# JBoss 6.1 properties-service.xml deleted properties still accessible

Tags: properties, jboss6.x

I can access the properties, specified in the `properties-service.xml`. But if I delete a property, the property is still accessible. If I modify a property, the property is changed.

Why is the deleted property still accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `remove(final String name)`  of the `SystemPropertiesService` is not implemented correctly.

The reason is a wrong method call in `org.jboss.util.property.Property`.

The remove method on this call looks like this:

```java
public static String get(String name, String defaultValue)
{
      return PropertyManager.getProperty(name, defaultValue);
}
```

See also: [org.jboss.util.property.Property: remove property is broken](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-3871)